# How can I display server files to browser with Java Spark

Tags: webdav, spark-java

I have started using Java Spark to with my Java application, running an embedded server, the idea being my software can then be controlled by a browser from a phone/ipad with the server running on Pc/mac ecetera.

I want the user to be able to browse folders on my server from their browser so I was thinking that webdav might be the answer, but how do I do this with java-spark, are there other solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems just using standard Java classes to generate file list and passing it to browser and then using jstree or similar to browse it is the way to go